# ASP.NET Identity - Not Authorized Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to plug into the default switch statement in the AccountController and redirect the user to a "Not Authorized" page if they aren't in the Admin role.

**Default Code**

```
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
    }
}
```

**Here's what I'm trying to add to the *SignInStatus.Success* case of the switch statement**

```
switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
        //After successful login - check if the user is not in the admin role
            if (!UserManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Admin"))
            {
                //Send to the Not Authorized page
                return View("NotAuthorized");
            }
            //Successful login with admin role
            else
            {
                //Return to where they came from 
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            //Lockout settings in IdentityConfig.cs
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
```

This all works fine if I start out at Account/Login, but if my URL has a ReturnURL attached, I can't get it to redirect to the Not Authorized page.

For example I have an Admin controller that looks like this.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    // GET: Admin
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

If I try to go directly to that Admin page, when not logged in, my page will redirect to Account/Login and the URL will look like this `http://localhost:51250/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAdmin`
This is where the redirect to NotAuthorized during login **won't** work.  If my URL looks like this `http://localhost:51250/Account/Login` the redirect to NotAuthorized **will** work.

It should ignore the return URL when going through my switch statement, I don't see what I'm missing.

Comment: return View will not redirect, and the returnurl is just a query string which wont effect the redirection either. I am having trouble understanding your question

Comment: OK, if I go to the login page at Account/Login and I don't have the role of "Admin", my switch statement will check the role and it will reach the `return View("NotAuthorized");` part of the code.  I will then end up on the NotAuthorized page(view).
If I try the same thing, but having been redirected to Account/Login from another page (now I have a returnURL attached) I will not end up on the NotAuthorized page, even thought it still reaches the same code `return View("NotAuthorized");` in my switch statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't doing a redirect.  You are telling it to use the NotAuthorized view for the Login action.  To do a redirect use RedirectToAction().

```
return RedirectToAction("NotAuthorized");
```

You will need to add a NotAuthorized action in your Account controller if you don't already have one.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult NotAuthorized()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Outstanding.  This works.  I'm not sure I fully understand why my situation wasn't working though.